# Does execute breakes the PDO Transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am writing user input to 2 MySQL tables as follows:

(a) insert some data to table-A,

(b) get the lastInsertId,

(c) insert other data to table-B.

I have:

```
            $this->conn->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO requests
                        ($creation_date, etc...) // some data 
                        VALUES(:creation_date, etc..);"); // some values


            $stmt->bindparam(":creation_date",$creation_date);
            ...

            $stmt->execute();
```

At this point, ultimately what I need is just to get the lastInsertId, 
but it seems it only becomes available afterthe first `$stmt->execute()` as otherwise it returns 0 due to fact that specific actions within transaction have not been physically started (please confirm if otherwise).

Further code as follows:

```
            $lastInsertId = $this->conn->lastInsertId();

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO other_requests
                        (requests_id,...) // some more data 
                        VALUES(:requests_id,...);"); // some more values

            $stmt->bindparam(":requests_id", $lastInsertId);
            $stmt->bindparam(...); // some more bindings
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->conn->commit();
```

**Questions:**

1. I am concerned if the first `$stmt->execute();` in the middle of transaction code somehow interrupts the transaction. My understanding is that it shouldn't - but so far haven't haven't found any good proof to that.
2. I am in search for a more elegant solution, as currently it seems there's too much code for a simple task.

Thanks for any advise

Comment: `$stmt->execute(['requests_id' => $lastInsertId]);`. You have not asked any questions in your post though. There is nothing to answer.

Comment: It shouldn't,  a transaction is only interrupted if it is rolled back or committed, committing makes your changes to the database permanent while a rollback takes your db state to where it was before you began your transaction.

Comment: @mendez7 it is also "interrupted" if an error occurs.

Comment: It doesn't look like "too much code" to me. Personally, I'd separate out the generation of the SQL text into a separate line of code, into a variable, and then passing that variable into `prepare`. That gives me a convenient spot for debugging, to log (or emit) the generated SQL text. Personally, I'd use `bindValue` in place of `bindParam`. I'm going to assume that `$creation_date` is guaranteed to be safe to include in the SQL text, and we're not open to SQL Injection there.

Comment: hey all, thanks for thoughts and comments, really usefull to have this thoughts. @spencer7593 For putting sql query to separate $sql var, I'll be definitely doing that. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does execute break the PDO Transaction?

No.

execute() is to execute the query. without execute() your query won't be executed. If no query is executed, then no information will be stored in the database. Without information stored in the database, no transaction will ever make sense. Therefore, to have a transaction, you have to store a data in the database. To store a data in the database, you have to execute a query. To execute a query you have to call execute().

Hope it is all clear now.